# SugarCRM filter PYTHON

Tags: python, sugarcrm

How to filter (for example Leads) by using the /filter endpoint of SugarCRM REST API? I tried this way but I think this is absolutely wrong.

```
url = "https://" + sugar_instance + "/rest/v10/Leads/filter:[{u'name':u'XXXXX'}]"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "OAuth-Token": access_token}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`
```

Most of the SugarCRM documentation are written using PHP which I have no knowledge of.

Comment: What do you mean "I think this is absolutely wrong"? What is the output you're getting? What is the output you're expecting? Is there an error?

Comment: I get a [404]. I added a lead that already exists

Comment: Are you sure about the `u` left of the `'`? Because that is already in the string contents.

Comment: tried without 'u' too.. same response.
i want to know the way the url is used in filtering out data from sugarcrm. there are so many examples for php but not for python with which i have to work with.

Comment: @PabasaraRanathunga I think the main mistake here is that you specify the filter directly in the URL, not even in the query string.
Check out http://<yoursugarinstance>/rest/v10/help

Try `"/rest/v10/Leads?filter=[{'name':'XXXXX'}]"`

Comment: or `"/rest/v10/Leads?filter=[{'name':{'$starts':'XXXXX'}}]"` even

Comment: I managed to filter out at last :) I'll post it as the answer

Comment: @Jay 
It suggestion gave a [422] 'invalid parameter in the request'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for my requirement. Here I passed a json object as the payload. Apparently the filtering done in php or bash should be sent as the payload.

```
url = "https://" + sugar_instance + "/rest/v10/Leads/filter"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "OAuth-Token": access_token}
payload = {"filter":[{"$or":[{"first_name":{"$starts":"E"}},{"first_name":{"$starts":"S"}}]}],"max_num":100,"fields":"name","order_by":"date_entered","favorites":False,"my_items":False}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

worked right for me.